# Call Email Validity Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a rather simple, basic, newbie question. I want to validate email addresses upon entry, so I have created (by copying from better minds) a dbo.udf_ValidateEmail scalar function, but am not sure how or where to call the function.

Ideally, I would like to use the Default Value or Binding property similarly to how I use the built-in (getdate()) function to autofill the InsertDate field, but am not sure if that is the right way to accomplish the intended validation or even the proper syntax if that is the right way.

Function Declaration is: udf_ValidateEmail (@email varChar(255))

Could someone please tell me where and how to call the Email Validate function? I am especially hung up on the syntax of how to pass the email field entry parameter to the function. I have searched extensively and found much discussion of this particular email validation subject, but the actual where and how solution eludes me. TIA.

> Edit <

My apologies if I didn't provide enough information initially. Hopefully this helps.

I want to call this function to validate a correct email address entry.

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ValidateEmail] (@email varChar(255))

RETURNS bit
AS
begin
return
(
select 
    Case 
        When    @Email is null then 0                       --NULL Email is invalid
        When    charindex(' ', @email)  <> 0 or     --Check for invalid character
                charindex('/', @email)  <> 0 or --Check for invalid character
                charindex(':', @email)  <> 0 or --Check for invalid character
                charindex(';', @email)  <> 0 then 0 --Check for invalid character
        When len(@Email)-1 <= charindex('.', @Email) then 0--check for '%._' at end of string
        When    @Email like '%@%@%'or 
                @Email Not Like '%@%.%'  then 0--Check for duplicate @ or invalid format
        Else 1
    END
)
end

I would like to call if from the Default Value or Binding property of the Column Property. Does that make sense? If not, where from should I be calling it?

Comment: What does the function do? What does it return? You need to give us some kind of information here. As it sits right now there isn't even a full question asked.

Comment: If you want to validate user input you can try looking at AJAX and make a separate aspx file that validates

Comment: It might help you get more responses if you add the all the technology involved.

Comment: It's just a SQL Server 2008 Scalar User Defined Function.

Comment: Have you looked into SQL Server insert triggers?

Comment: I have not, but I'm sure going to now. :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have a built-in data entry module.  Typically data is added by INSERT statements either natively or within stored procedures that are called by third-party code such as .Net or PHP.

Comment: Okay, then I will try to accomplish with front-end application code rather than at the DB level. I was hoping to avoid redundancy between a windows VB app and web app. I thought I could call the function natively upon input, but guess not.

Comment: You could call your function within a stored procedure to insert data and then return an error code if it was invalid.  Then you could use the same SP within both your VB and web app.